# How does one block all HTTP traffic on DNS level using unbound?

Tags: 21.04

I'm using Unbound as a resolver, and I'm curious if there's a way to block all HTTP traffic with it; in 2021, every website that doesn't use HTTPS is garbage.

Prajwal

Comment: Blocking outgoing HTTP traffic will have implications on your software updates. You may want to consider the broader implications of your objective.

Comment: Purely informational, or recreational websites, that process no confidential information, do not have reasons to be served via HTTPS. HTTP is still good enough for these sites.
Also, DNS has nothing to do with HTTP/HTTPS. You can use DNS to block access to a particular **domain** altogether, but not to individual services on that domain. That's firewall's job, not DNS's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the goal is to block your *browser* from accessing web content without an SSL certificate, you can do this with FireFox by setting HTTPS-Only mode.

In FireFox, go to settings and scroll right to the bottom. You'll see an option to enable HTTPS-Only mode:

[image: FireFox - HTTPS Only]

This will try to upgrade insecure connections to a site and, if the visiting site does not support HTTPS, a message will be shown letting you know (better than a blank page) that there is no SSL certificate. You can [read more about FireFox's implementation of HTTPS-only mode via their documentation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/https-only-prefs).

Chromium-based browsers, as far as I can tell, do not yet have any feature like this.

Of course, if you *really* want to block all HTTP traffic, you can do this:

```
sudo ufw deny out 80
```

This will break all sorts of things almost immediately, but you'll have your wish: zero requests will leave your computer over HTTP.

Comment: Re blocking outgoing port 80: not quite. Port 80 is the standard port for HTTP, but HTTP can and often will be spoken over other TCP ports. 8080, for example, is quite popular.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is: no.
A DNS resolver cannot block traffic.
It can only resolve DNS queries.

Comment: You have no idea what you're talking about, my good sir.

Comment: If you say so. Pray tell me how a DNS resolver would be able to block traffic then.

Comment: Before the resolver send the traffic to a certain website, we tell the resolver to forward it to 0.0.0.0 or some other ip that's invalid.

Comment: @PrajwalKoirala DNS has *zero awareness* as to whether you're talking over HTTP or HTTPS or not (it only speaks DNS it is not protocol-aware of what's going to use the DNS resolution - and as a Network Security expert by trade I can guarantee this).  That's an Application level issue, *not* a DNS one.  You're talking about Firefox's HTTPS only mode or similar HTTPS Everywhere plugins in Chrome/Chromium.  The pnly alternative to those plugins  is to block all outgoing traffic to port 80 on your firewall in an Outboud direction, however this will break your non-HTTPS things like ubuntu updates.

Comment: @PrajwalKoirala and Unbound, BIND, SystemD-ResolveD, etc. are all **DNS Servers and Clients** - they only know about DNS, and only can speak DNS, they can't resolve based on the requested protocol (HTTP/HTTPS), because they only know DNS and not the application level protocols that you're talking about which happen *outside* of DNS

Comment: You need to sort out a few basic concepts. The resolver does not send any traffic anywhere. It just resolves domain names to IP addresses. (Or other RRs, but that's irrelevant for this discussion.) It never even sees what your application program eventually does with that IP address. If the resolver returns 0.0.0.0 for a query on a certain host name then the application's connection attempts to that host will fail for HTTPS as well as HTTP, SSH, Ping or whatever protocol the application tries to use.

Comment: On the other hand, if the application uses an explicit IP address instead of a host name then it can connect to it with HTTP, HTTPS or any other protocol without the DNS resolver having any say in it. That's what I meant by: a DNS resolver cannot block traffic.